# How to repeat or retry with dynamic values using Project Reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, repeat, project-reactor

I have a method that makes a service call and returns a value as a Mono. Until I get the desired value, I have to repeat the execution of this method, with some backoff.

I am trying to solve this requirement using the `repeat()` functionality of Project Reactor.

A simplified example of my use-case would be something like,

```
Mono<Boolean> evaluateValue = fetchValueFromService(id)
          .filter(value -> {
            if (value != requiredValue) {
              id++;
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          })
          .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat
              .onlyIf(repeatContext -> true)
              .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));
evaluateValue.subscribe();
```

The problem with this approach is that we cannot update the value of `id` since

> Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

I was able to overcome that using an `AtomicReference`.

```
AtomicReference<Integer> id = new AtomicReference(0);
Mono<Boolean> evaluateValue = fetchValueFromService(id.get())
          .filter(value -> {
            if (value != requiredValue) {
              System.out.println(id.incrementAndGet());
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          })
          .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat
              .onlyIf(repeatContext -> true)
              .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));
evaluateValue.subscribe();
```

However, this is not solving the problem as only the initial value is being passed each time. I wonder if this is because Mono is immutable and cannot be changed?

Is there any other way to solve this issue? Will it be possible to dynamically update the parameter/argument used by the method (which is being repeated)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **create** / **generate** methods [here](http://www.vinsguru.com/reactive-programming-flux-create-vs-generate/) for dynamically generating flux / mono.

This could solve your problem.

```
  Mono.create(sink ->
        sink.success(fetchValueFromService(id.get()))
    )
```

For ex:

```
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Mono.create(sink -> sink.success(atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()))
            .repeat(10)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Will print up to 10 from 0.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `fetchValueFromService(id.get())` with `Mono.defer()`